# How to open Flash Player in Webview

Tags: android, browser, webview, flash

I have a web game that uses Flash Player. I want to make its android app. But when I use webview and set

```
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  //  webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true); //Can not resolve method ERROR!
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
```

Then load url

```
webview.loadUrl("http://example.com");
```

But it does not load when it comes to Flash Player Screen. 
It gives

> The plugin is not supported

ERROR.

On the other hand, it is loaded on successfully
[Puffin browser.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudmosa.puffinFree&hl=en)
How Puffin browser load Flash Player games in Android? 
How can I solve this problem? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Android 4.2 and later Flash support on WebView is gone